# Phone's Back Button doesn't work my WebView Flutter App, Any one to assist

Tags: android, flutter, dart, webview

I am trying to make my code work when phone's back button is tapped on a device(phone) the webview should be taken to the previous page, Now im having trouble getting the hardware back button to work. The app loads fine as does page and everything else but as soon as i hit the phones back button it crashes then forces close.
Here is my code

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class WebViewApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WebViewAppState createState() => _WebViewAppState();
}

class _WebViewAppState extends State<WebViewApp> {
  final Completer<WebViewController> _controller =
      Completer<WebViewController>();
  //int _currentIndex = 0;
  double opacity = 0.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (Platform.isAndroid) WebView.platform = SurfaceAndroidWebView();
  }

  @override
  public void onBackPressed() {
    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
      webView.goBack();
    } else {
      super.onBackPressed();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        toolbarHeight: 1,
      ),
      body: Opacity(
        opacity: opacity,
        child: WebView(
            initialUrl:
                'https://google.com',
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController controller) {
              _controller.complete(controller);
            },
            onPageFinished: (_) {
              setState(() {
                opacity = 1.0;
              });
            }),
      ),
    );
  }

  void onTabTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      //_currentIndex = index;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not have access to your stacktrace & I see that you are using `webView.canGoBack()` where I cannot see the `webView` variable.
Also, it is the `_controller` that handles the navigation like:

```dart
if (_controller.canGoBack()) _controller.goBack();
else super.onBackPressed();
```

More info. on the WebViewController: https://pub.dev/documentation/webview_flutter/latest/webview_flutter/WebViewController-class.html